# Unable to use my NSString object in my tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Sorry for the lack of detail in the title, but it's something I'll have to explain.

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *selectedEvent = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *eventTitle = [selectedEvent objectForKey:@"Title"];
    NSString *detailMessage = [[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat: @"You pressed the button for %@.", eventTitle];

    childController.message = detailMessage;
    childController.title = eventTitle;
```

The code gives me a reason: `'-[__NSCFType objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a19ee0'`

What event title gives you is justpiece of text. I've used it in my data source methods but for some reason in the delegate it won't let me use it.

The following is how the dictionary is setup. Keep in mind it's just a snippet:

```
NSDictionary *row1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: poster, @"Poster", @"The Addam's Family", @"Title", @"Dancap Productions", @"PresentedBy", @"The weird and wonderful family comes to devilishly delightful life in THE ADDAMS FAMILY.", @"Description", nil];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: row1, nil];

self.list = array;
```

Edit:

Here is the full class. I'll need to know what I'm leaking if I am to learn!

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondLevelViewController.h"
@class EventsDetailController;

#define kPosterValueTag 1
#define kTitleValueTag 2
#define kPresentedValueTag 3
#define kDescriptionValueTag 4


@interface EventsButtonController : SecondLevelViewController {
    NSArray *list;  //array holding all of the events
    EventsDetailController *childController;
    NSString *theatreType;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *list;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *theatreType;

@end




#import "EventsButtonController.h"
#import "TCA_BaseAppDelegate.h";
#import "EventsDetailController.h";

@implementation EventsButtonController
@synthesize list;
@synthesize theatreType;


-(void)viewDidLoad{

    //table heading
    UIView *containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 60)] autorelease];
    UILabel *headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 60)] autorelease];
    headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Header for the table", @"");
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [containerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView;
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0);
    //end table heading

    //poster image
    UIImage *poster = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test_poster.png"];

    NSDictionary *row1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: poster, @"Poster", @"The Addam's Family", @"Title", @"Dancap Productions", @"PresentedBy", @"The weird and wonderful family comes to devilishly delightful life in THE ADDAMS FAMILY.", @"Description", nil];

    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: row1, nil];

    self.list = array;

    [row1 release];
    [array release];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


-(void)viewDidUnload{

    self.list = nil;
    [childController release], childController = nil;

}

-(void)dealloc{

    [list release];
    [childController release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Data Source Methods

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [list count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier = @"DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier"; //set identifier for the cell

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier]; //set the identifier for dequeue ie. cells hidden from the screen

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];  //put this stuff first so we can retrieve the size of the text
    NSDictionary *rowData = [list objectAtIndex:row];

    if(cell == nil){

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                    reuseIdentifier:DisclosureButtonCellIdentifier] autorelease];

        //start adding custom subviews to the table cell

        //add subview for the poster
        UIImageView *posterValue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,105,175)];
        posterValue.tag = kPosterValueTag;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:posterValue];
        [posterValue release];

        //addsubview for the Title
        UILabel *titleValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,10,185,30)];
        titleValue.tag = kTitleValueTag;
        titleValue.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:titleValue];
        [titleValue release];

        //addSubview for the PresentedBy
        UILabel *presentedValue = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,30,185,30)];
        presentedValue.tag = kPresentedValueTag;
        presentedValue.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:presentedValue];
        [presentedValue release];


        //addSubview for Description
        UILabel *descValue = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        NSString *descString = [rowData objectForKey:@"Description"];
        CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(185, 140);
        UIFont *descFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
        CGSize descStringSize = [descString sizeWithFont:descFont 
                                       constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                                           lineBreakMode:descValue.lineBreakMode];
        CGRect descFrame = CGRectMake(125, 60, 185, descStringSize.height);
        descValue.frame = descFrame;

        //descValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        descValue.font = descFont;
        descValue.tag = kDescriptionValueTag;
        descValue.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        descValue.numberOfLines = 0;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:descValue];
        [descValue release];
    }


    //add content
    UIImageView *poster = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kPosterValueTag];
    poster.image = [rowData objectForKey:@"Poster"];

    UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kTitleValueTag];
    title.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Title"];

    UILabel *presented = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kPresentedValueTag];
    presented.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"PresentedBy"];

    UILabel *desc = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kDescriptionValueTag];
    desc.text = [rowData objectForKey:@"Description"];

    //add accessoryType for chevron icon.
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone]; //disables the blue highlight when the cell is selected
    [rowData release];
    return cell;


}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table Delegate Methods

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //makes the next drill down's button have the label of "back"
    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];
    [newBackButton release];

    if(childController == nil){
        childController = [[EventsDetailController alloc] initWithNibName: @"EventsDetail" bundle:nil];

    }

    childController.title = @"Disclosure Button Pressed";
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSDictionary *selectedEvent = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *eventTitle = [selectedEvent objectForKey:@"Title"];
    NSString *detailMessage = [[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat: @"You pressed the disclosure button for %@.", eventTitle];

    childController.message = detailMessage;
    childController.title = eventTitle;

    [detailMessage release];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController animated:YES];

}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 195;
}

@end
```

I dont know if I'm right, but in the Data Source method when I utilize the Dictionary objects within the list array I assigned them to rowData and then I released them. Am I releasing the actual dictionary object and not a instance of them? Therefore, I am left with nothing in the list array? If that's the case do I not release them ever?

Comment: see my edits. I didnt think it was relevant because the exact same code works in my Data Source methods. Oh and list is an instance array and I have used @property/@synthesize.

Comment: Definitely looks like a memory management issue, but from the code posted I only see possible leaks which would not cause that crash. You should probably be using self.list. Look for any code that modifies self.list or list (especially releases)

Answer (score 0):

1. properly deallocate objects when you no longer own them.
2. What is list? Is it retain or assign more detail is needed.

The error says that your calling a method in an object that doesn't recognize it so it may mean you accidently released the object and your calling a method on garbage memory.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *list; Is that what you mean? See my full code above. Thank You

Comment: your calling objectForKey for something that isn't a NSDictionary check put a breakpoint and debug. check what is in the NSArray and the NSDictionary using GDB. PO will print the object out and your can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

Insert this line between 2nd and 3rd line of first piece of your code,

```
if ([list isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] {
    NSLog(@"It's NSDictonary");
}
```

to make sure you actually got `list` as a `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Well, it's not a `NSDictionary`, and you're trying to do ` [selectedEvent objectForKey:@"Title"];` on it, that's where the error is. Make sure you actually get a `NSDictionary` before calling `objectForKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

ISTM that it could be that, when you access `list` after initializing the `childController`, `viewDidLoad` might not have run yet (on `self`), and in that case, `list` is still `nil`.

Since invoking methods on `nil` is simply handled silently, you don't get a runtime error yet. But your `selectedEvent` variable still contains garbage. Now, if you call `[selectedEvent objectForKey: row]`, you call that on garbage, and that probably causes the runtime error.

Try a few things:

### Use NSLog

- Add an NSLog entry in viewDidLoad to indicate the routine was called:

  ```
  NSLog(@"viewDidLoad")
  ```
- check if `list` is not `nil` before you access it. Use

  ```
  NSLog(@"self.list: %@", self.list);
  ```
- check `selectedEvent`:

  ```
  NSLog(@"selectedEvent: %@", selectedEvent);
  ```

That will show you what happens. If necessary, add more NSLog entries.

### Debug

Put a breakpoint on the line where you access `self.list` and in `ViewDidLoad`. Inspect the variables, single step the code, etc. This should give you more insight in what might be happening.

We can't see such things, from here. ;-)

Comment: can you look at the last paragraph? I removed that rowData release and it worked. But im not sure if that's wrong. I'm assuming that since rowData is in list and list is released, everything get's released.